# How do I pass in the 'hd' option for OpenID Connect (Oauth2 Login) using the Google Ruby API Client?

Tags: google-oauth, google-api-ruby-client

The ["Using Oauth 2.0 for Login"](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login?hl=ja#hd-param) doc lists the 'hosted domain' parameter as a valid authentication parameter, but using the [Google API Client for Ruby](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/wiki/OAuth2?hl=ja) linked at the bottom I don't see how to pass it along with my request. Anyone have an example?

Answer (score 1):

OK, wasn't perfect, but I just passed it to the authorization_uri attribute on the authorization object  like so

```
client = Google::APIClient.new 
client.authorization.authorization_uri(:hd => 'my_domain')
```

I still had trouble updating the Addressable::URI object to save the change (kept getting a "comparison of Array with Array failed" error), but this was good enough for me to use.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it to work using the Google::APIClient but managed to get it working using the OAuth2::Client like this

> SCOPES = [
>          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
>      ].join(' ')
>
> client ||= OAuth2::Client.new(G_API_CLIENT, G_API_SECRET, {
>                      :site => 'https://accounts.google.com', 
>                      :authorize_url => "/o/oauth2/auth", 
>                      :token_url => "/o/oauth2/token"
>                    })
>
> ...
>
> redirect client.auth_code.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => redirect_uri,:scope => SCOPES,:hd =>  'yourdomain.com')